# codesandbox.io / vuetify: two "identical" projects behaving differently

Tags: vue.js, codesandbox

I have two "identical" sandboxes,
[Sandbox A](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-dialog-demo-code-forked-jj9ld?file=/src/main.js) and [Sandbox B](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-checkbox-no-v-modal-forked-gowbj?file=/src/main.js)

I trimmed down the files and code to a minimum, and copy-pasted the code from one to the other,
including the package.json, so they should even have the same dependencies.

The only difference I can see at this point is where they were "Forked from". However, A is not displaying properly, while B does!

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandbox B has the [Material Icons font setup in `index.html`](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-checkbox-no-v-modal-forked-gowbj?file=/public/index.html:300-434), while Sandbox A does not. Without the icons, the `<v-icon>` component renders the icon name instead of the icon.

[demo of Sandbox A fixed](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-dialog-demo-code-forked-lfk3u)